# Move Menu Navigation (Margin?)

Tags: html, css, styling

I need to move this navigation menu above the content box and below the logo. In other words, the order should be: (1) logo, (2) menu, and (3) content box.

I tried various margin adjustments to the CSS for `#navigation` to no avail.

How do I do this?

URL: http://ec2-174-129-169-80.compute-1.amazonaws.com/

See screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add `top: -57px;` to your #navigation CSS like so:

```
#navigation {
    position: relative;
    top: -57px;
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    display: none;
    font: 14px/14px sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #D9D9D9;
    background: white;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(white), to(whiteSmoke));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, whiteSmoke);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, white 0%, whiteSmoke 100%);
    background: -moz-gradient(center top, white 0%, whiteSmoke 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a jsFiddle or post your code please. Without seeing code, first thoughts are that you put the `#navigation` in the content area. If that's the case, then:

```
#navigation { margin-top: -50px; }
```

If `#navigation` is absolutely positioned:

```
#navigation { top: -50px; }
```